# Django: subsequent OR filter

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a set of items with a GeneraricForeignKey field, and I want to loop through a set of objects to get the items attached to those objects, like so. I was thinking of doing a single queryset on ALL records, then adding filters to get the items attached to objects in my list.

Like so:

```
models.py:
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Item(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

views.py:
my_objects = list()
my_objects.append(SomeObject.objects.get(id=1))
my_objects.append(SomeObject.objects.get(id=2))

items = Item.objects.all()
for obj in my_objects:
    items = items.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), object_id=obj.id)

return items
```

When I look at the query for this, the separate filter for each object in the list is getting logically ANDed to the filter. Is there a way I can logical OR it? I tried this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
items = Item.objects.all()
for obj in my_objects:
    items = items.filter(
        Q(id__in=items)
        | Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), object_id=obj.id)
    )
```

but it doesn't actually exclude any records, because the or allows them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is construct the ORed clause separately:

```
object_filter = Q()

for obj in my_objects:
    object_filter =  object_filter | Q(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj),
            object_id=obj.id)

items = Item.objects.filter(object_filter)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I wasn't sure how to construct the filter, didn't know I could call it a Q() and then add to it. Tried with string construction and then eval(), but I knew that was not the most appropriate solution. Works perfectly!